# Mobx property are not pass to component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, mobx

My component check if the value already load, if not fetch data..

```
@withRouter @inject('myStore') @observer
class Component extends Component {    
  componentDidMount() {
    const { myStore, match } = this.props;
    const { selected, fetch } = myStore;

    console.log('DidMount with', selected, match.id);

    if (!selected || selected.id !== match.id) {
      fetch();
    }
  }
}
```

And I test ...

```
test('call fetch if id is different from match', () => {
  const props = { myStore: new MyStore(), match: { id: 321 } }
  const spy = jest.spyOn(props.myStore, 'fetch');
  props.myStore.selected = { id: 123 };
  shallow(
    <ClassRoomRobots.wrappedComponent {...props} />,
  );

  expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(321);

  spy.mockReset(); spy.mockRestore();
});
```

This is an simple store ..

```
class MyStore {
    @observable selected = undefined;
    @action fetch() {
        // Fetch data...
    }
}
```

### Problem

in my tests, the component is render with

> DidMount with **UNDEFINED** 321

Why `undefined` ? what's I miss here?